# Temporary image upload script?

Tags: image, upload, scripting

Hey guys! i just want to know if you know any free image upload script where you upload your images temporary. I need the image files to be deleted over time.

Comment: The context is lacking, to say the least.  Which operating system? Is it to be run from a web page? If so, which language..  Take a step back and re-read your question.  Details is everything.  OctaneFX took a guess at php/web page, but who really knows?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a way/method/script. Write a code which delete image files once they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic?
No way, you can aways use like this simple example:

```
$id=(int)$_GET['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM imagens WHERE img_id=".$id;
$exe=mysql_query($sql, $conect);
if($exe) unlink($_GET['arq']); 
mysql_close ($conect);
```

look, in a effective system, you need moore checks for a secure code :)